# About the tensor product of module

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I know that $M_F$ = $M \otimes F$ over $R$ module; 
$R$ is PID and $F$ is a field of a fraction. Show that for all $t \in M_F$ there exist $a \in R$ such that $at \in M$.

Say $t=x \otimes y$ where $x \in M$ , $ y \in F$  such that $y = \frac{a}{b}$ and $a,b \in R$.

Thus, $bt = b(x \otimes \frac{a}{b}) $. So $ bt = x \otimes a$ by properties of tensor $bt \in M$.

Comment: You are too lazy to write the equation in latex and expect someone to help you?

Comment: And what is the question exactly? Are you trying to verify whether your argument works?

Comment: yes @awllower I am verifying my argument. I know there some flaw there

Comment: The flaw is that you only considered a pure tensor,and an element in the tensor product is a finite sum of pure tensors.

Comment: Can you please explicitly write it  @Bernard so it clears to me?

Comment: Here you are: an element of $M_f$ has the form $x_1\otimes y_i+\dots x_n\otimes y_n$ for some $n$. Hence you first have to reduce the fractions $y_1, \dots,y_n$ to the same denominator.

Comment: ohh thanks bernard